# How to check user's age with Javascript based on 3 seperate inputs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have 3 seperate inputs, one for day, month and year. Only the year is required to show on page load, the user only needs to fill in the year first.

Currently I am able to check if someone is over 16 or under 16 by simply checking the year.

```
checkAge() {
    let yearOfBirth = new Date().getFullYear() - this.form.dobYear;

    if (yearOfBirth > 16) {
      this.isSixteen = false;
      this.belowSixteen = false;
    }
}
```

When comparing the current year minus the user's input, if it equals to 16, then I have two **select** elements displaying the day and month, both of these will need to be filled in.

Here I need to compare the users input to see if the age is indeed 16, if they are a few months away from there 16th birthday for example then I want them to be seen as below 16, otherwise show them as 16 years of age.

I am using BootstrapVue and Vue.js also if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check only the year:

```
function calculateYearDiff(y){ // birthday year
   return (new Date()).getUTCFullYear() - y;
}
```

^This will return difference in years between now and given year.

To check full birthday date:

```
function calculateAge(y,m,d){ // birthday year, month, day
   var birthday = new Date(y + '-' + m + '-' + d);
   var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday.getTime();
   var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);
   return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}
```

^This will return full years between given birthday and now.

Comment: Since the first time user prompts only the year he should manually fill other fields? (like assuming 1 of january)

Comment: @NicolòCozzani not sure what do you mean, op said that user inputs year, month and day

Comment: Probably i misunderstood what op was saying, i tought user should first fill year input and then others :)

Comment: That's correct, user should fill in the year first, and then based on this they will be shown the date and month dropdowns. @NicolòCozzani

Comment: @ImranR and then month and then day or just year and then month and day at once?

Comment: @FlashThunder They fill in the year initially only, if they put in 2003 (the current year minus 2003 = 16) for example, then they will be shown the day and month, both day and month will need to be filled in at once.

Comment: @ImranR so just combine my function with yours, edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

Get current `Date`

```
var base=new Date();
```

decrease it by 16 years

```
base.setFullYear(base.getFullYear()-16);
```

make a `Date` object from user input

```
var birthday=new Date(y,m,d);
```

compare the two

```
if(birthday.getTime()<=base.getTime())
  // ok
else
  // not ok
```

---

```js
function check(event){
  var base=new Date();
  res.innerText="It is "+base;
  base.setFullYear(base.getFullYear()-16);
  res.innerText+="\n16 years ago it was "+base;
  var bday=event.target.valueAsDate;
  if(bday)
    res.innerText+="\nVerdict: "+(bday.getTime()<base.getTime()?"Okay":"Too young");
}
```

```html
Birthday: <input type="date" oninput="check(event)" value="0"><br>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: I just tried this, but when i pass 2003,12,30 for birthday, it shows up as Fri Jan 30 2004, why is the date different to what I've passed? @tevemadar

Comment: @ImranR my code does not do anything with the birthday, so it is unclear why would it modify it. Instead I suspect that you missed the part that `getMonth()` and `setMonth()` (both of which are not used here) are 0-based (see docs, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth). So 0 is January and 11 is December, and when it under/overflows, it is previous/next year, that is how 12 is January next year. So no, you did not try this. Added a runnable snippet, by the way.

Comment: (btw. not just `get/setMonth()`, but months in general are zero-based with [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), see explanation about `monthIndex`)