# How can I get the correct birthdate format if the user inputs month, day and year separately?

Tags: javascript, date, validation

I have a form with three number type inputs: month (MM), day (DD) and year (YYYY). Once the user puts in their birthdate, I want to be able to take the values and verify whether they are over the age of 19 or not.

```css
input,
select {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form id="verification-form">
        <label for="month"></label>
    <input type="number" id="month" name="month" maxlength="2" placeholder="MM">
    <label for="day"></label>
    <input type="number" id="day" name="day" maxlength="2" placeholder="DD">
    <label for="year"></label>
    <input type="number" id="year" name="year" maxlength="4" placeholder="YYYY">
    <button type="submit" id="verify">VERIFY</button>
</form>
```

I know how to compare the birthdate once it is parsed into the correct date format. How do I do this in plain JavaScript? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check user's age with Javascript based on 3 seperate inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57866463/how-to-check-users-age-with-javascript-based-on-3-seperate-inputs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the birthdate with javascript by doing

```
 var month = document.getElementById("month").value;
 var day = document.getElementById("day").value;
 var year = document.getElementById("year").value;

 var birthdate = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
```

Now if you want to find the age and compare it to 19 on click verify here's the code.

```
 document.getElementById("verify").onclick = function () {
        var month = document.getElementById("month").value;
        var day = document.getElementById("day").value;
        var year = document.getElementById("year").value;

        var birthdate = new Date(year, month - 1, day);

        var today = new Date();
        var age = today.getFullYear() - birthdate.getFullYear();
        var m = today.getMonth() - birthdate.getMonth();
        if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthdate.getDate())) {
            age--;
        }
        
        if(age > 19){
            // Older than 19
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can simplify the calculation by: `if (new Date(+year + 19, month - 1, day) < Date.now())` then the date is more than 19 years ago. :-)

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much! Really appreciate it!